# JS / Node.js If and Else Statement issues

Tags: javascript, node.js

What my goal in this question is that when their is no `?_get` querystring, it automatically redirects to a URL with it. The problem is that when theres another querystring, I have to make the `?_get=` into a `&_get=` or else the Node.js app will keep adding `?_get=` until the browser ends it. I have tried using if and else if statements but they don't work, and the else if statement overrides the if statement. If I am not being clear enough please tell me in the comments.

Notes:

What req.cookies['origin'] is that its getting the previous querystring value from a cookie then putting that value into the redirect. It does not have a part in this issue.

```
const querystuff = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
  const query2 = querystuff._get

  if (!query2) {
    if (!req.query) {
    res.redirect(req.url + '?_get=' + req.cookies['origin']);    
    } else if (req.query) {
      res.redirect(req.url + '&_get=' + req.cookies['origin']);    
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have tried using if and else if statements but they don't work, and the else if statement overrides the if statement.  

<- would you clarify the else if statement overrides the if statement? what if statement are we talking about here? there's 2?

Comment: Use the `URL` API, e.g. `const redirectURL = new URL(req.url); redirectURL.searchParams.set("_get", req.cookies['origin']); res.redirect(redirectURL);`. No `if` statements necessary.

Comment: It didn't work at all and instead came up as ```TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL: /sp/search
    at onParseError (internal/url.js:257:9)
    ```